# How do you work with detached QueryOver instances?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

This [NHibernate blog entry](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx) notes how detached `QueryOver` queries (analogous to `DetachedCriteria`) can be created (using `QueryOver.Of<T>()`).  However, looking this over, it doesn't look analogous to me at all.

With DetachedCriteria, I would create my instance and set it up however I need, and afterwards call `GetExecutableCriteria()` to then assign the session and execute the query.  With the "detached" `QueryOver`, most of the API is unavailable (ie, to add restrictions, joins, ordering, etc...) until I call `GetExecutableQueryOver`, which requires takes an `ISession` or `IStatelessSession`, at which point you are no longer disconnected.

How do you work with detached `QueryOver` instances?

EDIT:

Actual problem was related to how I'm storing the detached QueryOver instance:

```
public class CriteriaQuery<T>
{
    internal protected QueryOver<T> _QueryOver { get; set; }

    public CriteriaQuery()
    {
        _QueryOver = QueryOver.Of<T>();
    }

    // Snip
}
```

It should be a `QueryOver<T, T>`.

Comment: What was the actual problem you mention below?

Comment: `QueryOver<T>` doesn't have the API I was expecting; `QueryOver<T, T>` is what I needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using NHibernate 3.1.0.4000.  The following code compiles successfully:

```
Employee salesRepAlias = null;

var query = QueryOver.Of<Customer>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.SalesRep, () => salesRepAlias)
    .Where(x => x.LastName == "Smith")
    .Where(() => salesRepAlias.Office.Id == 23)
    .OrderBy(x => x.LastName).Asc
    .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName).Asc;

return query.GetExecutableQueryOver(session)
    .List();
```

This illustrates using restrictions, joins, and ordering on a detached QueryOver just like you would with a regular one.

Could you please post the code that demonstrates the API features that are unavailable?

Comment: Selected your answer and added the actual problem to the question, cause your post pushed me towards the problem. Thanks.